# how to sort 1st column in ascending and if same then 2 nd column in descending in python?

Tags: python, sorting, reverse

I have a list `[('a',2),('h',5),('c',3),('h',4)]`. I want to sort it in such a way that first entry of each tuple is in ascending order. if there is a repetition ,then according to 2nd tuple entry in descending order in Python.
I want to get this :

```
[('a',2),('c',3),('h',5),('h',4)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second elements in your tuples are numerical (and thus valid operands for the unary `-` operator), you can use this simple key function:

```
lst = [('a', 2), ('h', 5), ('c', 3), ('h', 4)]
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
# [('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('h', 5), ('h', 4)]
```